TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf')
I am making a chat app using react and Firebase. I keep getting Type error either not being able to read undefined ('_delegate') or indexOf. There seems to be a problem with the useCollection hook.
const state = store.getState()
const serverId = useSelector((state) => state.server.serverId)

const inputRef = useRef('')
const chatRef = useRef(null)
const [user] = useAuthState(auth)
const serverRef = doc(db, 'servers', serverId)
const messagesRef = serverId ? collection(serverRef, 'messages') : null
const [messages] = useCollection(
    messagesRef ? orderBy(messagesRef?.timestamp, 'asc') : []
)
if (messages.error) {
    console.log(messages.error)
}

I map the messages via
messages?.docs?.map((doc) => {
    if (!doc.exists) return null
    const { message, name, photoURL, email, timestamp } = doc.data()
    return (
        <Message key={doc.id} id={doc.id} name={name} photoURL={photoURL} email={email} message={message} timestamp={timestamp} />
    )
})

How should I use my useCollection hook correctly?

You should initialize messagesRef and messagesQuery as null, construct the reference and query only if serverId is available, and pass the resulting query to useCollection.
let messagesRef = null;
let messagesQuery = null;

if (serverId) {
  const serverRef = doc(db, 'servers', serverId);
  messagesRef = collection(serverRef, 'messages');
  messagesQuery = query(messagesRef, orderBy('timestamp', 'asc'));
}

const [messages, loading, error] = useCollection(messagesQuery);


